# How to create extended type in a TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I want to show two seemingly identical situations, but they behave differently

**1)**

```
type User = { name: string, age: number };
const user1 = { name: 'Harry', age: 21, skills: 'backend', isAdmin: true }
const user2: User = user1; // NO ERROR
```

In this situation, TypeScript allows you to add additional properties to the object

**2)**

```
type User = { name: string, age: number };
const user2: User = { name: 'Alex', age: 23, skills: 'frontend' } // ERROR!
```

And in this case we will see an error, although the situations are quite similar

With this in mind, I have 2 questions:

**1) How to explain the difference in the behaviors above?**

**2) How do I declare a type that will cause the object to AT LEAST have all the necessary properties from the User type, and the rest of the properties can be completely different?**

Comment: The difference is that in the first case you are assigning the value from a variable, so typescript only checks if that variable has all the properties you have in the type (having extras is fine), in the second case you're assigning an object literal so typescript is a bit stricter on the type, wanting you to specify only and all the properties of the type

Comment: For the second question, maybe optional properties can help, like this: `type User = { name: string; age: number; skills?: string; isAdmin?: boolean };`

Answer (score 2):

> 1. How to explain the difference in the behaviors above?

In the first line you are creating an anonymous object. So no type checking is applied. In the second line you are specifically telling typescript that your object is of type **User**, so compile-time check was applied.

> 2. How do I declare a type that will cause the object to AT LEAST have all the necessary properties from the User type, and the rest of the properties can be completely different?

You can take help of **Intersection** typescript types. something like this

```
type User = { name: string, age: number };
type NewUser = User & {[key:string]:any}
const user1: NewUser = { name: 'Harry', age: 21, skills: 'backend', isAdmin: true }
```

Answer (score 1):

For the second question, you can use

```
type User = { name: string; age: number; [key: string]: any };
```

Comment: Before using this i'd ask myself a question: does `User` need arbitrary properties or am i just being lazy with my types? :D